# Socket.IO mixing up query parameters in different namespaces

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm having trouble with query parameters in socket.io.

Server Side:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.of('/1').on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log(socket.request._query['test']);
});
io.of('/2').on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log(socket.request._query['test']);
});
io.of('/3').on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log(socket.request._query['test']);
});
```

Client side:

```
io('/1', {
    query: 'test=1'
});
io('/2', {
    query: 'test=2'
});
io('/3', {
    query: 'test=3'
});
```

Prints:

```
1
1
1
```

Instead of:

```
1
2
3
```

The rest is just a default express scaffold.

Why is the query parameter always 1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
io('/1', {
    query: 'test=1',
    multiplex: false
});
io('/2', {
    query: 'test=2',
    multiplex: false
});
io('/3', {
    query: 'test=3',
    multiplex: false
});
```

Does the trick. See https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2632